# Disable bounces in scroll view disable horizontal scroll in pageView Controller

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Only the first view show then when i want to scroll to the second view it doesn’t scroll
P.S i have pageView controller and this code inside it

```
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {

            scrollView.delegate = self

            scrollView.bounces = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it the utilities when you select the scroll view in the.

[image]